# Firefox occasionally not rendering its own window when opened

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, firefox, kde

Sometimes when I open Firefox, the content of Firefox window doesn't render at all, it gets a frame from the window behind and render nothing else. This issue seems relatively random as multiple open/close cycles seem to temporally fix the issue.

I run Kubuntu 21.10, KDE plasma 5.23.4 on my laptop (X11 session).

Comment: Same problem with xfce. Do you happen to have a Nvidia GPU? It seems that EGL support is broken for Nvidia.... looking for a solution myself..

Comment: Yes I have an Nvidia GPU that is disabled, I found out a solution that worked for me, check the accepted answer @kanehekili

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where you have only Nvidia card, you can try the solution in the other answer.

Turns out it has something to do in the case when you disable the Nvidia card and use integrated graphics. Firefox seems to be trying to render through the disabled GPU. To fix add this to your `.profile`:

```
if ! grep -w -q nvidia <(lsmod) ; then export
__EGL_VENDOR_LIBRARY_FILENAMES="/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/50_mesa.json"
fi
```

logout then login and the problem is solved.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/rnergb/firefox_shows_blank_screen_after_upgrading_to_2110/)

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurs in XFCE on a device with a NVIDIA GPU:

Random transparency on focus change, flickering or partial repaints

The following entries [Firefox 95 and newer] in "about:config" helped:

```
gfx.webrender.software.opengl -> true, 
gfx.webrender.software -> false 
gfx.swap-interval.egl ->false 
gfx.egl.prefer-gles.enabled->false 
layers.acceleration.disabled -> false 
gfx.webrender.all ->false
```

and most important:

```
layers.acceleration.force-enabled -> true
```

Restart firefox

Comment: Isn't this disabling hardware acceleration for OpenGL?, could you also try the other solution I found?

Comment: Not possible, I can't disable my only GPU. And yes, it is disabling at least some part of the HW acceleration. The problem started with FF 93.